# How to use project to remove file with populated document

Tags: mongoose, aggregate, project, populate

I have an aggregate query and I use populate, like in the query, but when I use project for remove some fields it didn't work, 
it seems that i removed the fileds before they were populated

is there any solution ? thanks

**query**

```
var model = myFirstModel;
var features = featureModel;

  model.aggregate([

                { "$match": {
                    "field1": true,
                    "field2":true

                }},
                {
                    "$project":{
                        "feature.updatedAt" : 0
                    }
                },

                {
                    $lookup:
                        {
                            from: "features",
                            localField: "_id",
                            foreignField: "user_id",
                            as: "user_id"
                        }
                },{ "$unwind": "$user_id"  }
            ])

                .exec(function (err, doc) {
                   features.populate(doc, {path: 'user_id.features.mi_id'}, function(err, populated) {
                            features.populate(populated, {path: 'user_id.feature.ma_id'}, function(err, populated2) {
                               callback(populated2)
                            });
                      });
                })   
        },
```

Comment: which version of mongodb you are using?

Comment: mongo version 4

Comment: It would be better if you post sample collection and the output